# Need suggestion for WiFi router

Tags: wifi, router

I have 100 Mbps broadband plan. I want to limit it to 1 Mbps for guest network so that streaming and other things would work smoothly on my main network. Which router is suitable for me(in India)?

Comment: Can you explain your use case in brief that how are you going to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know in the US that the Netgear Nighthawk series allows for this and works well. I have a Netgear Nighthawk R7800, and that works a charm. We previously had a Netgear Nighthawk R6900P and that also worked a charm. These routers are quality routers but may be pricy in India.

I'd recommend one of these:
[Netgear Nighthawk R6700](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00R2AZLD2),
[Netgear Nighthawk R6900P](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07C65K9H9),
[Netgear Nighthawk R7000P](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NA80JML), or
[Netgear Nighthawk R7800](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0192911RA)

All of these will last long, well-rated in the US, reliable, user-friendly and have room for expansion. They'll cover a 3-story house well and even outside of the house.

If you want a mesh network (a series of small routers linked together), I would use the [Eero mesh system](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WMLPSRL) they will cover .7 acres of land extremely well and if there are any slow-spots in the house/property, you can buy more than just one pack of three and hook it up. They are extremely user-friendly and easy to set up. The only issues with them are that you can't set them up with a computer, you must use the Eero app on an Android or iOS device, and you can't limit the speed on the guest network.

Comment: thanks, i found similar one [here](https://www.amazon.in/Netgear-Nighthawk-AC2300-MU-MIMO-Dual-Band/dp/B075JMF84S?th=1)

Answer (score 2):

You need a router approved for use in your locale with  [Quality of Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) (QoS), sometimes referred to as *Internet Access Policy*, features [introduced in this article](https://itstillworks.com/use-router-limit-peoples-internet-usage-1431.html).  Since I am not in India, my shopping results won't tell me what's available to you, but if you search for "WiFi router Internet Access Policy" or "WiFi router Quality of Service", you will see what's available.